# MIPS - Storing ints In Array From User Input

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to store user input into an array, but when I use sw I get an error "store address not aligned on word bound". My goal is to read in 10 integers from the array, but after I input the first digit I get an error at the sw command. I don't know what I'm doing wrong I spent a couple hours trying to figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated and marked useful.

```
        .data 

mess: .asciiz " Enter 10 numbers to be stored in the array. "
array: .space 40    #10 element integer array
    .globl main
    .text 
main:
    jal read
    b done
read:
    la $t0, 0   #count variable
    b readLoop
    jr $ra

readLoop:
    beq $t0, 40, read   #branch if equal to 40, 10 items
    li $v0, 4       #Print string
    la $a0, mess        #load prompt
    syscall
    li $v0, 5       #read int
    syscall 
    sw $v0, array       #store input in array ERROR HERE
    addi  $t0, $t0, 4   #add by 4 to count
    b readLoop
print:

done:
```

This worked for me. I don't know why it doesn't work above

```
    .data 
list:  .space 16
.globl main
.text

main:

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw $v0, list

    move $a0, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try allocating space for your array before you allocate space for your string in the data segment:

```
  array: .space 40    #10 element integer array
  mess: .asciiz " Enter 10 numbers to be stored in the array. "
```

if you allocate the string first the array might start at an address that is not divisible by 4 and lead to a word alignment error

Answer (score 2):

- The store should be

  sw $v0, array($t0)
- Replace `la $t0, 0` by `li $t0, 0`
- Set the array above `mess`

Furthermore, when you reach 10 items, you restart the reading and overwrite the previous values.

Answer (score 2):

**Proper Array Input Code**

```
.data
    myarray:.space 40    
    st:.asciiz "Enter the 10 Elements"

.text    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,st
    syscall
    jal fun
    li $v0,10
    syscall

fun:        
    li $v0,5
    syscall
    beq $t0,40,exit
    sw $v0,myarray($t0)
    add $t0,$t0,4
    j fun

exit:
    jr $ra
```

Comment: Please use markdown formatting to make that more readable. And please add some explanation, in order help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will read in input from the user up the amount they enter, if they want to enter 10 integers the initial input must be 10. Then it will prompt the user to fill in the integers one at a time. After the initial array will be printed.

A project of mine required me to have sort functionality so that is implemented in the second part of the code at swap to implement ascending order sorting. Any clarifications contact me.

```
.data 
    inputLabel: .asciiz "Enter the amount of integers in the array: "
        myArray: .space 100
    
    arrayToBeSorted: .asciiz "Enter the array to be sorted one at a time: "
    nextLine: .asciiz "\n"
    original: .asciiz "You have entered: "
    result: .asciiz "Here is the sorted list in ascending order: "

.text 

.globl main

main: 
        #print input label
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, inputLabel
    syscall 

        #read amount of integers to be inputed.
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    addi $t0, $v0, 0

        #put input into $t0, number of integers in array
    
    addi $t7, $t0, 0
    li $t4, 4
    #mul $t5, $t0, $t4

        #ask user to input numbers of the arrayToBeSorted
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, arrayToBeSorted
    syscall

    li $t6, 0 
    #used to index array at insertion
    
    j loop0

        #read the numbers 
    loop0:         #loop successfully reads in n integers and stores them in a list

            #check if 0 == input;
        beq $t7, 0, next
            #take in user input
        li $v0, 5
        syscall
            #store user input into list
        sw $v0, myArray($t6)
            #add 4 to the index of the list
        addi $t6, $t6, 4
            #sub 1 from the number of items to add to list
        addi $t7, $t7, -1
            #loop
        j loop0

    next: #success print
        move $t0, $t6
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, original
        syscall
        j while 

    while: #printer success

        #print new line
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, nextLine
        syscall

        beq $t6, $zero, swap 
            #dif i is 0 then exit
        lw $t1, myArray($t3)
            #load in my array at index i
        
        #printing int at myArray[i]
        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t1
        syscall  

        addi $t3, $t3, 4
        addi $t6, $t6, -4

        j while 

swap:

    la $t4, myArray 
    #loads A[0] myArray to $t4

    la $t1, myArray 
    #loads A[1] array to $t1
    
    addi $t1,$t1,4 
    #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1
    
    la $t8,myArray 
    #loads A[n] array to $t8
    
    add $t8,$t0,$t8 
    #add $t8 to $t0, save to $t8
    
    la $t9,myArray
    
    add $t9,$t0,$t9 
    #add $t9 to $t0, save to $t9
    
    addi $t9,$t9,-4 
    #subtracts 4 from $t9, save to $t9 A[n-1]

loop:

    lw $t2,($t4)
    #load A[0] input into $t2

    lw $t3,($t1) 
    #load A[1] input into $t3

    blt $t2,$t3,loop1 
    # dif $t2 < $t3, A[0]<A[1]go to loops

    sw $t3,($t4) 
    #store $t3 in $t4 A[1] = A[0]

    sw $t2,($t1) 
    #store $t2 in $t1 A[0] = A[1]

loop1:

    addi $t1,$t1,4 
    #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1 A[1] + 4 becomes A[2]
    blt $t1,$t8,loop 
    #dif $t1<$t8, go to loop A[2] < A[n]
    addi $t4,$t4,4 
    #add 4 to $t4, save to $t4
    move $t1,$t4
    addi $t1,$t1,4 
    #add 4 to $t1, save to $t1
    blt $t4,$t9,loop 
    #idf $t4<$t9, to go loop

print:

    la $a1,myArray 
    #loads myArray to $a1
    la $a0, result
    #loads output to $a0
    li $v0, 4 
    #loads 4 into #v0
    syscall
    la $a0, nextLine 
    #loads nextLine into $a0
    li $v0, 4 
    #loads 4 into $v0
    syscall

loop2:

    blez $t0, done 
    #if $t0<=0, go to done
    li $v0, 1 
    #loads 1 into $v0
    lw $a0, 0($a1) 
    #load an inout into $a0
    syscall
    la $a0, nextLine 
    #loads nextLine into $a0
    li $v0, 4 
    #loads 4 into $v0
    syscall
    addi $a1, $a1, 4 
    #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1
    addi $t0, $t0, -4 
    #subtracts 4 from 
    #t0, save to $t0
j loop2

    done:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    j done
```

Comment: Comments like `add $t8,$t0,$t8      #add $t8 to $t0, save to $t8` are just redundant, not helpful.  Reiterating how MIPS syntax works for every normal instruction is clutter that distracts from *useful* comments like `addi $t9,$t9, -4  # address of A[n-1]`.  Also, some of your comments under the part I happened to look at, `swap:`, are wrong.  `la $t1, myArray` doesn't load `A[1]`, and doesn't even load the *address* of `A[1]`.  It's the address of `A[0]`, same as you got from `la $t4, myArray`.

Comment: You're doing the same `la` 4 times in one loop for no apparent reason; you could keep that in a reg that you set once outside the loop, and just do stuff like `addu $t1, $t8, $t0  # myArray + n_byte_offset`.  (Note how the comment explains the *semantic* meaning in terms of one level of logic higher up, using variable names, instead of repeating the register names, since you can see that from the instruction itself.)

Comment: Also you can and should use stuff like `lw $t2, 4($t4)` instead of using a separate `addiu` to offset a pointer register.  `lw` / `sw` are I-type, taking a 16-bit immediate offset from the register, so you only have to spend instructions on address calculation with runtime variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
.p2align 2
array: .space 40    #10 element integer array
...
```

Comment: This didn't change anything.Thanks for responding though.

Comment: Did you get any compilation error? `.p2align 2` is supposed to align the following code/data on an address that's a power of 2 (2^2=4 here). What if you add one to three extra characters to the `mess` string? That could fix the alignment of `array` as well.